# Two horizontal lines around UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a login table that give to my users many forms to create a account, inside my table I have a cell with a UILabel, all I'm trying to do is create two horizontal lines around the UILabel like this image below:

[Example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkpkq.jpg)

That image have two horizontal lines around the label **OR**, what better way to do this? And how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create lines out of very thin `UIView`s with a background color of gray or black. In storyboard, drag a UIView in front of the UILabel in the cell, size according to your preferences, and copy it to make one after the label as well.

Comment: Another way is to use UIImageView with an image possibly  of height 1 px.

Comment: Tim's answer of using a generic view is the right way to do this. (Voted.) You just set the background color on the view and you make it any size by setting the proper constraints with no custom code needed. With an image view you either need a custom image for each size, or need to stretch the image, neither of which is ideal.